# Photoshop Feathering is far too pixelated

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I've had a big problem with a recent picture that I want to cut certain parts out of in Photoshop to edit, but annoyingly the feathering from the polygonal lasso tool is extremely pixelated and I have no idea why. The picture is 5742x3648 and this hasn't happened to me on smaller pictures. What is wrong and how can I fix it?

[image: The problem.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Blending Mode of your Layer is set to Dissolve. Change it to Normal and you should be set.

[image: Photoshop screenshot]